# Why are my Action creators not dispatching data to redux store in Next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I just started using NextJS for the first time and I'm trying to use it with Redux.
I have been able to set up the redux and set up the getServerSideProps function in index.js.
The problem however is that the store returns an empty state even after I have fetched the data. When I console.log the fetched data from inside the getServerSideProps function, I see it in my terminal, so I'm left to suspect that the problem is that my action creator is not dispatching the data to the store. I even tried to handle the data fetching and dispatch from inside the action creator using redux-thunk, but that also did not work. Please I really need some help with this.

My action creator:

```
export const initializeArticles = (articles) => {
  return {
    type: 'INITARTICLES',
    data: articles
  }
}
```

My reducer:

```
const articlesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INITARTICLES':
      return action.data

    case 'ADDARTICLE':
      return state.concat(action.data)

    case 'INCREMENTARTICLELIKES':
      return state.map((article) => {
        if(article.id === action.id) {
          return {
            ...article,
            likes: article.likes + 1
          }
        } else {
          return article
        }
      })

    case 'DELETEARTICLE':
      return state.filter(article => article.id !== action.id)

    case 'ADDCOMMENT':
      return state.map((article) => {
        if (article.id === action.id) {
          return {
            ...article,
            comments: article.comments.concat(action.data)
          }
        } else {
          return article
        }
      })

    case 'APPROVECOMMENT':
      return state.map((article) => {
        if (article.id === action.articleId) {
          return article.commentIsApproved = true
        } else {
          return article.commentIsApproved = false
        }
      })

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default articlesReducer
```

My store setup:

```
let store;

const initstore = (initialState) => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  )
}

export const initializeStore = (preloadedState) => {
  let _store = store ?? initstore(preloadedState)

  if (preloadedState && store) {
    _store = initstore({
      ...store.getState(),
      ...preloadedState
    })

    store = undefined
  }

  if(typeof window === 'undefined') return _store
  if(!store) store = _store

  return _store
}

export function useStore(initialState) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeStore(initialState), [initialState])
  return store
}
```

My getServerSideProps function:

```
export const getServerSideProps = () => {
  const reduxStore = initializeStore()
  const { dispatch } = reduxStore
  getPosts().then((posts) => {
    console.log(posts)
    dispatch(initializeArticles(posts))
  })

  return { props: { initialReduxState: reduxStore.getState() } }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: you are calling your creator with no argument.

Comment: I actually did call it with an argument, just forgot to add that to the code when I posted it, I only removed the argument temporarily when I tried redux-thunk.

Comment: you definitelly should not call this `const reduxStore = initializeStore()` there. I suggest google react-redux example app.

Comment: I found the code sample here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux/pages/ssr.js

Comment: judging by the name the store gets initialized everytime you call getserversideProps. It is kind of misleading. I would find different examples.

Comment: Your comment is actually making me consider that perhaps I might have been looking at this the wrong way. I'm starting to consider if perhaps this is how it should indeed work. When I dispatch the same action creator inside the main component and then use the useSelector hook to get the state from the store, it does work. So perhaps the getServerSideProps function is only meant to get data already in the store at the time of initialization.